Trajectories in a two-strain SIS
In a two-strain SIS model, susceptible individuals $S$ become infected $I_1, I_2$ at rate $\beta_i I_i S/N$ and subsequently recover at rate $\gamma_i I_i$. Suppose $\frac{\beta_1}{\gamma_1} = \frac{\beta_2}{\gamma_2}$ and rescale to $x=I_1/N$, $y=I_2/N$. It's
\begin{aligned}
        \dot{x} &= x \left( \beta_1 (1-x-y) - \gamma_1 \right)\\
        \dot{y} &= y \left( \beta_2 (1-x-y) - \gamma_2 \right)
\end{aligned}
and the model will settle on the line $x+y=1-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}$.
My question is concerning the trajectories. Apparently, by "dividing the second equation by the first one and integrating the resulting differential equation for $y=y(x)$" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.0298) one will get $y=Mx^{\gamma_2/\gamma_1}$ with $M$ dependend on the initial conditions. I am at a loss here, as the derivatives on the left hand side are w.r.t. time, how am I supposed to integrate $\dot{x}/\dot{y}$?

Implicit differentiation of the function $y(x)$ yields $\dot{y} = \frac{dy}{dx}(x)\dot{x}\implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}$. You then integrate the differential equation for $y$ as a function $x$. time is eliminated
